# how to populate my chartjs piechart dynamically

Tags: javascript, chart.js, pie-chart, adminlte

please help me how can i populate this chartjs piechart dynamically from my database data to be displayed it with piechart. i mean getting a query from my database and convert the data given by my database to compatible with the data need from the chartjs format. Please help me.

I am using ajax to get the values from my db:

```
function getpieclinic() {
    $.ajax({
       url: siteurl+"patients_report/piedataclinic",
       type: "GET",
       dataType: "JSON",
        success:function(response) {
            alert(response);
        }
    });
}
```

the code below has a value of JSON OBJECT WITH THESE QUERY RESULT (response value):

```
[{"clinic_name":"Clinic 1","total_checked_up":"4"},{"clinic_name":"Clinic 2","total_checked_up":"0"},{"clinic_name":"Clinic 3","total_checked_up":"0"},{"clinic_name":"Clinic 4","total_checked_up":"0"}]
```

[image]

Here is the data from piechart sample to be followed:

```
var pieChartCanvas = $("#pieChart").get(0).getContext("2d");
    var pieChart = new Chart(pieChartCanvas);
    var PieData = [
      {
        value: 700,
        color: "#f56954",
        highlight: "#f56954",
        label: "Chrome"
      },
      {
        value: 500,
        color: "#00a65a",
        highlight: "#00a65a",
        label: "IE"
      },
      {
        value: 400,
        color: "#f39c12",
        highlight: "#f39c12",
        label: "FireFox"
      },
      {
        value: 600,
        color: "#00c0ef",
        highlight: "#00c0ef",
        label: "Safari"
      },
      {
        value: 300,
        color: "#3c8dbc",
        highlight: "#3c8dbc",
        label: "Opera"
      },
      {
        value: 100,
        color: "#d2d6de",
        highlight: "#d2d6de",
        label: "Navigator"
      }
    ];
    var pieOptions = {
      //Boolean - Whether we should show a stroke on each segment
      segmentShowStroke: true,
      //String - The colour of each segment stroke
      segmentStrokeColor: "#fff",
      //Number - The width of each segment stroke
      segmentStrokeWidth: 2,
      //Number - The percentage of the chart that we cut out of the middle
      percentageInnerCutout: 50, // This is 0 for Pie charts
      //Number - Amount of animation steps
      animationSteps: 100,
      //String - Animation easing effect
      animationEasing: "easeOutBounce",
      //Boolean - Whether we animate the rotation of the Doughnut
      animateRotate: true,
      //Boolean - Whether we animate scaling the Doughnut from the centre
      animateScale: false,
      //Boolean - whether to make the chart responsive to window resizing
      responsive: true,
      // Boolean - whether to maintain the starting aspect ratio or not when responsive, if set to false, will take up entire container
      maintainAspectRatio: true,
      //String - A legend template
      legendTemplate: "<ul class=\"<%=name.toLowerCase()%>-legend\"><% for (var i=0; i<segments.length; i++){%><li><span style=\"background-color:<%=segments[i].fillColor%>\"></span><%if(segments[i].label){%><%=segments[i].label%><%}%></li><%}%></ul>"
    };
    //Create pie or douhnut chart
    // You can switch between pie and douhnut using the method below.
    pieChart.Doughnut(PieData, pieOptions);
```

Comment: any answers plss i need it

Answer (score 0):

I think you are stuck at to create Piedata for the chart form JSON. Here is the Solution:

Your JSON string:

```
$json = '[{"clinic_name":"Clinic 1","total_checked_up":"4"},{"clinic_name":"Clinic 2","total_checked_up":"0"},{"clinic_name":"Clinic 3","total_checked_up":"0"},{"clinic_name":"Clinic 4","total_checked_up":"0"}]';
```

First Convert it to array:

```
$array = json_decode($json);
```

Declare the Empty variable:

```
$string_array = '';
```

Loop Threw the Array:

```
foreach($array as $single_array){

    $string_array[] = array(
    'value'=>$single_array->total_checked_up,
    'color'=>'#f56954',
    'highlight'=>'#f56954',
    'label'=>$single_array->clinic_name
    );  
}
```

Convert the array into JSON again to get your desired PieData:

```
var PieData  = json_encode($string_array);
```

This is how your PieData data look like.

```
[
    {
        "value": "4",
        "color": "#f56954",
        "highlight": "#f56954",
        "label": "Clinic 1"
    },
    {
        "value": "0",
        "color": "#f56954",
        "highlight": "#f56954",
        "label": "Clinic 2"
    },
    {
        "value": "0",
        "color": "#f56954",
        "highlight": "#f56954",
        "label": "Clinic 3"
    },
    {
        "value": "0",
        "color": "#f56954",
        "highlight": "#f56954",
        "label": "Clinic 4"
    }
]
```